# Pandas Comparing hourly multiple year data in one plot

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

So I have a pandas dataframe, called year, on this form:

```
                           discharge (m^3/s)  
date                                                                   
2016-01-01 00:00:00           17.6930
2016-01-01 01:00:00           17.3247
2016-01-01 02:00:00           17.2436
2016-01-01 03:00:00           17.5696
2016-01-01 04:00:00           16.4074
2016-01-01 05:00:00           17.5696
2016-01-01 06:00:00           17.0420            
....
2017-12-31 20:00:00           10.5911           
2017-12-31 21:00:00           10.5620          
2017-12-31 22:00:00           10.7374          
2017-12-31 23:00:00           10.5620
```

The dataset contains discharge data for several years and I want to do a plot comparing f.ex. the month of january for the years 2016 and 2017.

My attempts thus far has been to extract the wanted months and just plotting them on top of each other. But this does not work as you can see in this picture:

[Attempt plot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AP1aJ.png)

My code for this was:

```
# Comparison full months
def plotmonthdischarge(month, years, number_of_years):
    df = pd.read_csv('resources\FinVannføringEidsfjordvatn.csv', encoding = 'ISO-8859-1',sep=';')
    df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'],dayfirst=True)
    df = df.set_index(df['date'])
    df['Day Of Year'] = df['date'].dt.dayofyear
    df = df.drop(['date'], axis = 1)
    df = df.replace(to_replace='-9999', value = np.NaN)


    fig, ax = plt.subplots()

    # For a starting year 2016 and a 1 following year
    # Call example:
    # plotmonthdischarge(1,[2016],2)
    if len(years) == 1:
        start_year = years[0]
        for i in range(number_of_years):
            year = df['{0}-{1}-01 00:00:00'.format(start_year+i,month):'{0}-{1}-31 23:59:59'.format(start_year+i,month)]
            ax.plot(year['discharge (m^3/s)'], label = 'Year {}'.format(start_year+i))

    # Just for plotting(ignore)
    formatted_list = ['{:>3}' for i in range(number_of_years)] 
    string_of_years = ', '.join(formatted_list).format(*[start_year+i for i in range(number_of_years)])
    plt.title('Comparison plot of years {}'.format(string_of_years))

    # Specific years  2006 and 2017
    # Call example:
    # plotmonthdischarge(1,[2006,2017],1)
    if len(years) > 1:
        number_of_years = 1
        for item in years:
            year = df['{0}-{1}-01 00:00:00'.format(item,month):'{0}-{1}-31 23:59:59'.format(item,month)]
            ax.plot(year['Day Of Year'],year['discharge (m^3/s)'], label = 'Year {}'.format(item))

    # Just for plotting(ignore)
    formatted_list = ['{:>3}' for item in years] 
    string_of_years = ', '.join(formatted_list).format(*years)
    plt.title('Comparison plot of years {}'.format(string_of_years))
    print(year)

    plt.suptitle(r'Discharge $m^{3}s^{-1}$')
    plt.ylabel(r'Discharge $m^{3}s^{-1}$')
    plt.legend()
    plt.grid(True)

plotmonthdischarge(1,[2015,2016],1)
```

My next attempt was with something I found in other posts

```
df['Day Of Year'] = df['date'].dt.dayofyear
```

and then plotting over all the days in the month:

```
 ax.plot(year['Day Of Year'],year['discharge (m^3/s)'], label = 'Year {}'.format(item))
```

This worked okay except it seems like only one or so points per day gets registered which is bad since I'm working with hourly data.

[Attempt plot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cyMj7.png)

Also tried removing year from the datetime (my index) and plotting over a datetime index with only month, day and hours, but with no real success.

**EDIT**:

Example plot of how the plot of a single year (2015,january) would look like.

[Correct plot I get of only one year](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nsmKo.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your data has no missing values (`NaN`), I'd suggest slicing desired years out of the DataFrame with `.loc` and plotting the underlying numpy arrays with `.values`:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for yr in ['2016', '2017']:
    ax.plot(df.loc[yr].values, label = 'Year {}'.format(yr))
```

A more flexible way is to manually compute the *hour* of the year, rather than the day of year, and go from there:

```
df['hourofyear'] = 24 * (df.index.dayofyear - 1) + df.index.hour
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for yr, g in df.groupby(df.index.year):
    g.plot('hourofyear', 'discharge (m^3/s)', label='Year {}'.format(yr), ax=ax)
```

Comment: I implemented the first way and it seems to be working. This specific dataset does not contain NaN's tho but I would like it to work with datasets who do contain NaN's. Does one of your solutions work better than the other with NaN's?

Comment: @JohanR, yes, I'd go with the second approach.